# The image is rendered only once even though it is returned from a loop which is supposed to return it 50 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render an image using `for` loop in react component, but the loop doesn't work as expected. The picture is rendered only once when I call the function that is supposed to render same image 50 times and show 50 images in the screen

```
import React from 'react';
import dipesh from '../../dipesh.jpg';

export default function Tshirt() { 
    let renderTshirt = () => { 
        for(let i=0; i < 50; i++) {
            return( <img src={dipesh} alt="pic"/> )
        }
    }
    return ( <div> {renderTshirt()} </div> )
}
```

Comment: Post your code, for more clarification

Comment: Please post a relevant snippet

Comment: `import React from 'react';
import dipesh from '../../dipesh.jpg';

export default function Tshirt() {

let renderTshirt = () => {
        for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
            return(
                <img src={dipesh} alt="pic"/>
            )
        }
}

  return (
    <div>
      {renderTshirt()}
    </div>
  )
}`

Comment: U can use map instead

Comment: but i am trying to render same image multiple times... how can map help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import React from 'react';
import dipesh from '../../dipesh.jpg'; 

export default function Tshirt() {
 let renderTshirt = () => {
    let tShirtList = [];
    for(let i=0; i<50; i++){ 
      tShirtList.push( <img src={dipesh} alt="pic"/> );
    };
    return tShirtList;
 }
 return ( <div> {renderTshirt()} </div> ) 
}
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.